# Use Traefik with Docker Compose to serve 2 services on the same host but different routes

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, traefik

I have 2 frontend apps, both are served by Nginx in port 80

1. `app-login`
2. `app-contacts`

I'm trying to configure Traefik with Docker Compose to achieve this:

- Both apps are served on the same host (for example abc.com or localhost:4000)
- `app-login` will be accessed from localhost:4000/login (or abc.com/login)
- `app-contacts` will be accessed from localhost:4000/contacts (or abc.com/contacts)

But the problem is: it doesn't work with what I did so far.

Below are 2 `Dockerfile` of 2 apps and the `docker-compose.yml`

#### `app-login` Dockerfile:

```sh
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#### `app-contacts` Dockerfile: (a bit more complicated but it's just similar to login app)

```sh
### STAGE 1: Build the AngularJS app ###

FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

RUN apk --no-cache add git

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Production mode build
RUN npm run build:prod


### STAGE 2: Add Nginx for hosting the AngularJS app ###

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

# Removes the default nginx html files
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy the bundle
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy the default nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

VOLUME ["/usr/share/nginx/html/env"]

EXPOSE 80

# Copy .env file and shell script to container
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./scripts/generate_env.sh .
COPY .env .

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x generate_env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/generate_env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  app-login:
    image: app-login
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-login.rule=Path(/login)"

  app-contacts:
    image: app-contacts
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-contacts.rule==Path(/contacts)"
```

Not sure where I did wrong.

I searched Google and somewhere I see that people are using https://www.getambassador.io/ with this stack, but I don't know how to configure it either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue

Based on this link https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule

```sh
Backticks or Quotes?
To set the value of a rule, use backticks ` or escaped double-quotes \".

Single quotes ' are not accepted as values are Golang's String Literals.
```

So the rule must be

```
"traefik.http.routers.app-contacts.rule==Path(`/contacts`)"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Traefik listen on port 80. You have to replace "81:81" by "81:80". In you web browser, you have to use port 81, it will be mapped to 80 in Traefik container.

**EDIT:**

There are several syntax errors in your labels.

- == instead of = in last line
- Paths should be quoted with ``

If you check the Traefik Dashboard (http://localhost:8080/), you can see routers status and configuration errors.

With your current configuration, NGINX should take requets on path /login and /contacts not the default /. You can use below labels, the 2 additonal lines are useful if you want to remove the path part (login or contacts) before forwarding to the NGINX so you NGINX listen on default /.

```
  app-login:
    image: app-login
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-login.rule=PathPrefix(`/login`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-login.middlewares=app-login-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app-login-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/login"

  app-contacts:
    image: app-contacts
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-contacts.rule=PathPrefix(`/contacts`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app-contacts.middlewares=app-contacts-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app-contacts-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/contacts"
```

Comment: I updated `81:81` to `80:80` but it still does not work. I can `docker-compose up -d`, but after that, when I tried to go to localhost/login or localhost/contacts, it said `404 page not found`.  Btw, if I have this `- "traefik.http.routers.esn-frontend-login.rule=Path(/login)"`, what is the route that I have to type in the browser in order to open the page?